# C# ASP.NET Kendo Multiple Edit Commands on Single Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui

I'm trying to have multiple Kendo Edit commands on a single row. The total number of Edit buttons will be 6, along with 6 Kendo switches. Each command will have separate `emailSubject`, `emailBody`, and `emailAddress`, which are associated with each switch. I need each command to open a Kendo popup window and be able to update the associated `emailSubject`, `emailBody`, and `emailAddress`.

This is what I have so far: **JS file**

```
DailyLimits.Methods.KendoInit = function () {
DailyLimits.Controls.RenderedGrid = DailyLimits.Controls.DailyLimitsGrid.kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: emailAlerts,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "number", validation: { required: true } },
                    AccountNumber: { type: "string" },
                    CustomerName: { type: "string" },
                    Limit: { type: "number" },
                    CurrentUsage: { type: "number" },
                    EmailSubject: { type: "string" },
                    EmailBody: { type: "string" },
                    FromAddress: { type: "string" },
                    Alert1: { type: "boolean" },
                    Alert2: { type: "boolean" },
                    Alert3: { type: "boolean" },
                    Alert4: { type: "boolean" },
                    Alert5: { type: "boolean" },
                    Alert6: { type: "boolean" }
                }
            }
        },
    },
    filterable:true,
    height: "800px",
    groupable: true,
    sortable: true,
    scrollable: true,
    resizable: true,
    columnResizeHandleWidth: 5,
    columnMenu: true,
    toolbar: kendo.template($("#ToolbarTemplate").html()),
    columns: [
                { field: "AccountNumber", title: "Account Number", filterable: true, hidden: false, width: 100 },
                { field: "CustomerName", title: "Customer Name", filterable: true, hidden: false, width: 100 },
                { field: "Limit", title: "Daily Credit Limit", format: "{0:c}", filterable: true, hidden: false, width: 100 },
                { field: "CurrentUsage", title: "Current Usage", format: "{0:c}", filterable: true, hidden: false, width: 100 },
                { field: "Alert1", title: "75%", filterable: true, hidden: false, width: 100, "template": "<input type= \"checkbox\" class=\"mobileSwitch\" id=\"alert1-switch\" # if(Alert1) {# checked=\"checked\" #} # />" },
                {
                    command: [{
                        name: "Edit1",
                        title: "Alert 1 Email",
                        width: "180px",
                        click: function (e) {
                            // prevent page scroll position change
                            e.preventDefault();
                            // e.target is the DOM element representing the button
                            var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
                            // get the data bound to the current table row
                            var data = this.dataItem(tr);
                            console.log("Details for: " + data.AccountNumber);
                        }
                    }],

                },
                { field: "Alert2", title: "80%", filterable: true, hidden: false, width: 100, "template": "<input type= \"checkbox\" class=\"mobileSwitch\" id=\"alert2-switch\" # if(Alert2) {# checked=\"checked\" #} # />" },
                {
                    command: [{
                        name: "Edit2",
                        title: "Alert 2 Email",
                        width: "180px",
                        click: function (e) {
                            // prevent page scroll position change
                            e.preventDefault();
                            // e.target is the DOM element representing the button
                            var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
                            // get the data bound to the current table row
                            var data = this.dataItem(tr);
                            console.log("Details for: " + data.AccountNumber);
                        }
                    }],

                },
                { field: "Alert3", title: "85%", filterable: true, hidden: false, width: 100, "template": "<input type= \"checkbox\" class=\"mobileSwitch\" id=\"alert3-switch\" # if(Alert3) {# checked=\"checked\" #} # />" },
                {
                    command: [{
                        name: "Edit3",
                        title: "Alert 3 Email",
                        width: "180px",
                        click: function (e) {
                            // prevent page scroll position change
                            e.preventDefault();
                            // e.target is the DOM element representing the button
                            var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
                            // get the data bound to the current table row
                            var data = this.dataItem(tr);
                            console.log("Details for: " + data.AccountNumber);
                        }
                    }],

                },
                { field: "Alert4", title: "90%", filterable: true, hidden: false, width: 100, "template": "<input type= \"checkbox\" class=\"mobileSwitch\" id=\"alert4-switch\" # if(Alert4) {# checked=\"checked\" #} # />" },
                {
                    command: [{
                        name: "Edit4",
                        title: "Alert 4 Email",
                        width: "180px",
                        click: function (e) {
                            // prevent page scroll position change
                            e.preventDefault();
                            // e.target is the DOM element representing the button
                            var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
                            // get the data bound to the current table row
                            var data = this.dataItem(tr);
                            console.log("Details for: " + data.AccountNumber);
                        }
                    }],

                },
                { field: "Alert5", title: "95%", filterable: true, hidden: false, width: 100, "template": "<input type= \"checkbox\" class=\"mobileSwitch\" id=\"alert5-switch\" # if(Alert5) {# checked=\"checked\" #} # />" },
                {
                    command: [{
                        name: "Edit5",
                        title: "Alert 5 Email",
                        width: "180px",
                        click: function (e) {
                            // prevent page scroll position change
                            e.preventDefault();
                            // e.target is the DOM element representing the button
                            var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
                            // get the data bound to the current table row
                            var data = this.dataItem(tr);
                            console.log("Details for: " + data.AccountNumber);
                        }
                    }],

                },
                { field: "Alert6", title: "100%", filterable: true, hidden: false, width: 100, "template": "<input type= \"checkbox\" class=\"mobileSwitch\" id=\"alert6-switch\" # if(Alert6) {# checked=\"checked\" #} # />" },
                {
                    command: [{
                        name: "Edit6",
                        title: "Alert 6 Email",
                        width: "180px",
                        click: function (e) {
                            // prevent page scroll position change
                            e.preventDefault();
                            // e.target is the DOM element representing the button
                            var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
                            // get the data bound to the current table row
                            var data = this.dataItem(tr);
                            console.log("Details for: " + data.AccountNumber);
                        }
                    }],

                },

    ],
    editable: "popup",       
});
```

Here's what I have in my **DailyLimits.aspx** file, where I need the popup to happen:

```
<script id="alert1_popup" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div class="SearchParam">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtEmailSubject" style="width:200px">Email Subject</label>
        <input name="txtEmailSubject" id="txtEmailSubject" class="k-textbox" style="width:430px"
            data-bind="value:Alert1EmailSubject"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="SearchParam">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtEmailBody" style="width:200px">Email Body</label>
        <textarea name="txtEmailBody" id="txtEmailBody" style="width:350px"
            data-bind="value:Alert1EmailBody"
            data-role="kendo.ui.Editor"
        ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="SearchParam">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtFromAddress" style="width:200px">From Address</label>
        <input name="txtFromAddress" id="txtFromAddress" class="k-textbox" style="width:430px"
            data-bind="value:Alert1FromAddress"
        />
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open Kendo Window on each click event and pass unique parameter in query string (in data property of kendo window) to window that will help to identify each button click or where to save.

I hope this suggestion will help you !